# The identity iphone developer doesn't match any valid non-expired certificate

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm showing this message error when I'm trying to deploy an app on my iPad, I just installed OSX 10.8.4 to my iMac so I read that I should revoke and request the certification again, but could someone let me know if revoking the certificate can affect to the apps that I already have on the appstore?? or there is something else that I can do.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, revoking your current certificate and creating the new one will not affect your previous apps.